# Xamarin Android "namespace SqlConnection does not exist" even after putting directive. 2.How to connect an android app to a MSSQL database locally?

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android

Android.  Using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.
I'm trying to use

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
```

but as the title suggests it says that the namespace SqlConnection does not exist.  Even after I placed

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

It might have to do with the fact that it's greyed out and is saying "Using directive is unnecessary" googling around hasn't shown me an answer to how to stop it from greying out the using statement.

Please advise.

Second assuming I get this to work.  What would be the correct string to connect an Android app to my desktop database locally via TCP/IP?  (As in using private IPs when they're both connected to the same modem/router).  I'm guessing...

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=192.168.0.14,1433\\SQLEXPRESS;Database = mydatabase; User ID=test;Password=password";
```

This is for SQL Server 2016.  I already set it up to allow remote connections in "Server Management Studio" and TCP/IP in "SQL Server Configuration Manager"

I am aware after checking various other topics that it's not advised to connect directly to a database and to create something like a REST API etc (to which I'm not familiar with). This is only for school assignment purposes that I simply want the android app to send and retrieve data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following connection string to access the Sql Server on my local network:

connectionString="server=192.168.1.1;database=MyDB;uid=sa; pwd=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

This is from a web app that's been in production for about 8 years now, VS 2010 but should work in VS 2015.  I'm not really that into Sql Server, my database of choice is Oracle.  The reason I mention this is because I believe Sql Server client is now native in the framework and hence VS 2015, but could be wrong about that.  That is why, I believe, your using statement is greyed out.

One thing I do know though, your phone app won't connect to the database unless it's connected to your local network.  So if you're going to turn it in to class, it won't connect in their network.  I've developed both Android and iOS apps and use a webservice, only because it existed already, but REST is easy.  I'm using it in my latest apps.  I can provide sample code if you like.

R/
Prescott ...

Comment: Sure I'd appreciate that.  Been wracking my brain over understanding REST etc haha.

Answer (score 0):

This is the REST server part.  I got this example from someone, I forget where or who otherewise I'd credit them.  When you run this in the VS IDE, you will get an error message in the browser, REST doesn't display an interface like a webservice does, just ignore the error and you can accrss the functions in the REST demo on your local machine.  Open another instace of VS and write a REST client to access the REST service, run that and you'll see it work.  I added to the demo some of my Oracle access code, not what you need, but I'm too lazy to delete it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

namespace RESTFulDemo
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements
        (RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

    public class RestSerivce : IRestSerivce 
    {
        List<Person> objPerson = new List<Person>();
        int personCount = 0;

        public Person CreatePerson(Person createPerson)
        {
            createPerson.ID = (++personCount).ToString();
            objPerson.Add(createPerson);
            return createPerson;
        }

        public List<Person> GetAllPerson()
        {
            return objPerson.ToList();
        }

        public Person GetAPerson(string id)
        {
            return objPerson.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID.Equals(id));
        }

        public Person UpdatePerson(string id, Person updatePerson)
        {
            Person p = objPerson.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID.Equals(id));
           p.Name = updatePerson.Name;
            p.Age = updatePerson.Age;
           return p;
        }

        public void DeletePerson(string id)
        {
            objPerson.RemoveAll(e => e.ID.Equals(id));
        }

        public DataSet GETDS()
        {
            return new DataSet();
        }

        public OracleConnection OpenConnection(string pUserName, string pPassword)
        {
            OracleConnection functionReturnValue = default(OracleConnection);
            try
            {
                OracleConnection ConnObject = new OracleConnection();
                ConnObject.ConnectionString = "User ID=" + pUserName + ";password=" + pPassword + ";Data Source=Data";
                ConnObject.Open();
                functionReturnValue = ConnObject;
            }
            catch (Exception Exc)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error occured while connecting to the database, the error is: " + Exc.Message);
            }
            return functionReturnValue;
        }


        public string Logon(string pUsername, string pPassword)
        {
            OracleConnection MyConnection = OpenConnection("SuperUser_UserName", "SuperUser_Password");
            string MyReturnString = "";
            try
            {
                string MyUserType = GetUserType(MyConnection, pUsername);
                if (MyUserType != "")
                {
                    MyConnection.Close();
                    try
                    {
                        MyConnection = OpenConnection(pUsername, pPassword);
                        MyReturnString = "CONNECTED";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return "FAILED: Invalid Username or Password.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MyReturnString = "FAILED: Access Denied";
                }
                MyConnection.Close();
                MyConnection.Dispose();
                MyConnection = null;
                return MyReturnString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MyConnection.Dispose();
                MyConnection = null;
                return "FAILED: Invalid Uername or Password.";
            }
        }


        public string GetUserType(OracleConnection TheConnection, string pUsername)
        {
            string functionReturnValue = null;

            OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand();
            string Result = "";
            try
            {
                var _with1 = myCommand;
                _with1.Connection = TheConnection;
                _with1.CommandText = "SchemaName.UserData.GetUserType";
                _with1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _with1.Parameters.Clear();
                _with1.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pUserName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, pUsername.Length)).Value = pUsername;
                _with1.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pUserType", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                _with1.Parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                _with1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                functionReturnValue = _with1.Parameters[1].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error occured while retreiving user type, the error is: " + exc.Message);
            }
            myCommand = null;
            return functionReturnValue;

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: 1. The service interface part is what I put into the Android app right? 2. The REST server part I just delete the part's involving "OracleConnection" correct?

Comment: No, it all goes into VS.  On the VS menu its Project->Add New Item, from the Add New Item dialog select Visual C# Items->Code->Interface.  The interface code goes there.  Yes, delete the Oracle stuff.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/  Alright I'll review the code and also read this link and try to make the REST client.  Wait so REST compatible with Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

This is the service interface part:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace RESTFulDemo
{

    #region IRESTService Interface

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestSerivce
    {
        //POST operation
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
        Person CreatePerson(Person createPerson);


        //Get Operation
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
        List<Person> GetAllPerson();
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
        Person GetAPerson(string id);

        //PUT Operation
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{id}", Method = "PUT")]
        Person UpdatePerson(string id, Person updatePerson);

        //DELETE Operation
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{id}", Method = "DELETE")]
        void DeletePerson(string id);

        //GETDS Operation
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "GETDS")]
        DataSet GETDS();

        //Get Operation
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Logon?pUsername={pUsername}&pPassword={pPassword}")]
        string Logon(string pUsername, string pPassword);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Person Entity
    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID;
        [DataMember]
        public string Name;
        [DataMember]
        public string Age;

    }
    #endregion

}
```